# Why does animating <clipPath> works as expected, but animating it's children is glitched?

Tags: html, css, svg

**Working as expected:**

The rectangle appears from left to right and then disappears from left to right with the same speed

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#myClip {
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: right center;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect width="1" height="1" />
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>
```

**Broken:**

The rectangle appears normally but disappears ultra-fast

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

#myClip rect {
  animation: anime 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: right center;
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 140 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <rect width="1" height="1" />
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>
```

The only difference is changing `#myClip` selector to `#myClip rect`

Comment: I ran both snippets with longer time durations to see what was happening and neither gives the reverse effect you describe. In particular the first one instantly removes most of the rectangle right hand side. What have I misunderstood?